# Extending yang with help prompts for cli

Tags: command-line-interface, yang

I am writing a new CLI and I am considering using yang as a data definition language. It has almost everything I need: mandatory/optionals, types, derived types, acceptable ranges, descriptions and a ton of existing modules.

However, I want to provide short help prompts: type '?' and see possible values for the next field with a short help (say 60 chars max). And there are no short prompts in .yang structure as far as I know.

How one would add short prompt information to a .yang file? Have a companion file containing only short prompts? Extend .yang format? Embed this information in .yang comments?

I am sure I am not the first person doing it, what is the recommended practice? I suspect the answer is 'companion file' because it will work with existing .yang files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `description` statement is used to provide information for the module reader. If you want to provide a more user friendly text you can define your own statement.
YANG supports a `extension` statement for this purpose.

Define it:

```
module my-extensions {
       ...

   extension help {
       description "Takes as argument a help-text string.";
       argument "text";
   }
}
```

Use it:

```
module example {
   import my-extensions {
       prefix "myext";
   }
       
   container example {
       myext:help "This is an example container";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using description field as the help string source.